# Saving Checked / Unchecked Tasks to UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, userdefaults

How to save "Checked / Unchecked Tasks" to persist data with UserDefaults?

In my **ListViewModel**, I'm attempting to save the checkmarks Bool isCompleted state to UserDefaults. When you relaunch the App, the checkmarks reset to false.

Not sure if I need to add an EnvironmentObject or ObservableObject to the **ListView**

ListViewModel.swift

```
//
//  ListViewModel.swift
//

import Foundation

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items: [ItemModel] = [] {
        didSet {
            saveItems()
        }
    }
    
    let itemsKey: String = "task_items_list"
    
    init() {
        myTaskItems()
    }
    
    func myTaskItems() {
        let taskItems = [
            ItemModel(title: "This is the first task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the second task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the third task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the fourth task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the fifth task!", isCompleted: false)
        ]
        items.append(contentsOf: taskItems)
        
        guard
            let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: itemsKey),
            let savedTaskItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ItemModel].self, from: data)
        else { return }
        
        self.items = savedTaskItems
    }
    // Update TaskdItems Toggle
    func updateItem(item:ItemModel) {
        if let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) {
            items[index] = item.updateCompletion()
        }
    }
    // Save to UserDefaults
    func saveItems() {
        if let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(items) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: itemsKey)
        }
    }
}
```

ItemModel.swift

```
//  ItemModel.swift
//

import Foundation

struct ItemModel:Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let isCompleted: Bool
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, title: String, isCompleted: Bool) {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
        self.title = title
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
    }
    
    func updateCompletion() -> ItemModel {
        return ItemModel(id: id, title: title, isCompleted: !isCompleted)
    }
    
}
```

ListView.swift

```
//
//  ListView.swift
//

import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(listViewModel.items) { item in
                ListRowView(item: item)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        listViewModel.updateItem(item: item)
                    }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .navigationTitle("My Task List")
    }
    
    
    struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ListView()
            }
            .environmentObject(ListViewModel())
        }
    }
    
}
```

ListRowView.swift

```
//
//  ListRowView.swift
//

import SwiftUI

struct ListRowView: View {
    
    let item: ItemModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: item.isCompleted ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                .foregroundColor(item.isCompleted ? .green : .gray)
            Text(item.title)
            Spacer()
        }
        .font(.title2)
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
    }
}

struct ListRowView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var item1 = ItemModel(title: "First item!", isCompleted: false)
    static var item2 = ItemModel(title: "Second item!", isCompleted: true)
    
    static var previews: some View {
        
        Group {
            ListRowView(item: item1)
            ListRowView(item: item2)
        }
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

TaskListApp.swift

```
//
//  TaskListApp.swift
//

import SwiftUI

@main
struct TaskListApp: App {

    @StateObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel = ListViewModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ListView()
            }
            .environmentObject(listViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ScreenShot of My Task List]

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your `myTask` function. Everytime you initialize the `ListViewmodel` you are overwriting the `UserDefaults` with your initial array. Move that code into the `else` block of the guard statement.

```
func myTaskItems() {        
    guard
        let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: itemsKey),
        let savedTaskItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ItemModel].self, from: data)
    else {
        let taskItems = [
            ItemModel(title: "This is the first task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the second task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the third task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the fourth task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the fifth task!", isCompleted: false)
        ]
        items.append(contentsOf: taskItems)
        return
    }
```

This does fix the issue.

---

But I would ask you to consider a different approach that makes your code easier. You could use `@Appstorage` in combination with `@Binding`. Use the `@Appstorage` in the viewmodel and pass the `ItemsModel` via `Binding` down to the `ListRowView`.

I have commented the code as far as I thought it might help. If you have questions about this implementation feel free to ask.

```
//needed to use array in @Appstorage
extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable{
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
            guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
                  let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
            else {
                return nil
            }
            self = result
        }

        public var rawValue: String {
            guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
                  let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            else {
                return ""
            }
            return result
        }
    
}

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // this loads and saves the items automatic to UserDefaults
    @AppStorage("task_items_list") var items: [ItemModel] = []
    
    
    init() {
        //fill the collection only if it is empty
        if items.isEmpty{
            myTaskItems()
        }
    }
    
    func myTaskItems() {
        items = [
            ItemModel(title: "This is the first task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the second task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the third task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the fourth task!", isCompleted: false),
            ItemModel(title: "This is the fifth task!", isCompleted: false)
        ]
        
    }
    
    //The rest of the functions are not needed
}
        

struct ItemModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var isCompleted: Bool
}

struct ListView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            //Use the $ syntax to pass a binding on to the subviews
            ForEach($listViewModel.items) { $item in
                ListRowView(item: $item)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .navigationTitle("My Task List")
    }
}

struct ListRowView: View {
    //this binding will assure changes will bubble up into the viewmodel and will be saved in UserDefaults
    @Binding var item: ItemModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: item.isCompleted ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                .foregroundColor(item.isCompleted ? .green : .gray)
            Text(item.title)
            Spacer()
        }
        .font(.title2)
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
        // this is enough to toggle the checkmark
        .onTapGesture {
            item.isCompleted.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I go about the implementation using @Appstorage and @Binding I tried calling ListView() in ContentView but got a fatal error message. `ListView()`

Comment: @KraigKistler what is the error messsage precisely? I´ve tested the code and it should work.

Comment: AppTest crashed due to missing environment of type: ListViewModel. To resolve this add .environmentObject(ListViewModel(...))` to the appropriate preview. Show Crash Logs

Comment: SwiftUI/EnvironmentObject.swift:70: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ListViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ListViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
2022-09-10 20:16:24.269126-0700 ListView[59612:1765909] SwiftUI/EnvironmentObject.swift:70: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ListViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ListViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
(lldb)

Comment: @KraigKistler the error message seems pretty obvious. You are not passing you viewmodel to you Child views. Look at the code you posted in the question. In `TaskListApp` you are injecting you viewmodel into the environment. Why you removed that is unknown to me.

Comment: I have added the `extension Array` and `class ListViewModel` into ListViewModel.swift. I'm now getting ths one Error message for`@AppStorage("task_items_list") var items: [ItemModel] = []` ERROR MESSAGE **Unknown attribute 'AppStorage'**

Comment: @KraigKistler You would need to `import SwiftUI` in your ViewModel file.

Comment: Would you look at my post I can't figure out how to load data classes to multiple Lists it is a the code you help with in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73942323/get-data-from-model-for-multiple-list-views-observableobject-class-and-app-stora